# MadLib game having trouble

Tags: java, jgrasp

When I run it it doesn't ask me for the country for some reason but if i enter something it does show up at the end. Do I have to add something after the original question? Here is what I have done so far.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class MadLib
{
  private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {

   System.out.print("What country are you from and what is your name, also how old are you? ");  

   System.out.println("Enter your country > ");
   String country = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter your name > ");
   String name = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter you age > ");
   int age = in.nextInt();


   madlib(country,name,age);
   }

      public static void madlib(String country,String name,int age)
   {
      System.out.println(" I'm from "+country+" and my name is "+name+" , and I am "+age+" years old. ");
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line asking for the question should be `println` not `print`

```
System.out.println("What country are you from and what is your name, also how old are you? ");
```

The difference:

Println() won't print on a new line, it will terminate the current line with a newline character or sequence. In other words, println() will print an end-of-line character, while print() will not. If you invoke println() after a print(), the argument to println() will append to the argument to print().

from (http://www.coderanch.com/t/394386/java/java/system-print-println)